# How to get predefined paper size by PaperKind

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to get paper size by System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind. Are there any predefined values? I don't want to hardcode or calculate paper sizes, I just want to get it programmatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A subset of predefined values can be had by iterating over a `PrinterSettings.PaperSizes` collection.

Our application has the user select a printer, providing us with a [`PrinterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.aspx) object. Contained within `PrinterSettings` is a list of `PaperSize`'s supported by the printer - not everything (note that the XPS Document Driver (win7) supports all sizes).

In our case this subset of supported sizes is all we need. A user specified `PaperKind` is passed to our printing code, and it goes through our  `PrinterSettings` object until it either finds the user's selection or gives up and uses a default.

In the example below you can see that the `PaperSize` objects are correctly filled.

```
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
foreach (PaperSize size in settings.PaperSizes)
    Debug.WriteLine(size);
```

It's only a subset, but maybe that's also enough for you. the printing APIs in .NET are really unclear and msdn isn't really much help... Hopefully it puts you on the right track!

Answer (score 8):

A LINQ way to achieve your goal is something like this:

```
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
IQueryable<PaperSize> paperSizes = printerSettings.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().AsQueryable();
PaperSize a4rotated = paperSizes.Where(paperSize => paperSize.Kind == PaperKind.A4Rotated).FirstOrDefault();
```

Good luck!

Comment: // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602366/why-can-i-not-call-toarray-on-a-generic-ienumerable-object
using System.Linq;

Answer (score 3):

```
public static PaperSize GetPaperSize(string Name)
    {
        PaperSize size1 = null;
        Name=Name.ToUpper();
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        foreach (PaperSize size in settings.PaperSizes)
            if (size.Kind.ToString().ToUpper() == Name)
            {
                size1 = size;
                break;
            }
        return size1;            
    }
```

Comment: You need to add an explanation to your code. What does it do?

Comment: I got it working and it is the best solution so far, but according to practices here, you need to explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize class.  There's a RawKind property which can be set to a System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.

Something like:

```
PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
size.RawKind = (int) PaperKind.A3;
```

Comment: No. In this case height and width are still 0.

Comment: man, you'd think there's some sort of helper class for this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.paperkind.aspx lists each PaperKind along with the height & width.  Perhaps you should write a helper class and post it?

Comment: I have seen that enum class. But I wanted do not write any classes because there may be already written ones.

Comment: @hackerhasid, if [this](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Printing/PaperSize@cs/1/PaperSize@cs) is at all authoritative, it seems that someone "didn't think they needed it anymore", and commented out exactly that code (`#ifdef false`).  I haven't read an awful lot of the .NET source, but that's not an encouraging kind of remark :O

Answer (score 1):

```
PaperSize pkSize;
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count; i++)
{
    pkSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i];
    cmbPaperSize.Items.Add(pkSize);
}
```

Comment: Add a small explanation to your answer to explain why it works.

Comment: use this  using System.Drawing.Printing;

Answer (score 1):

Taking the comments and research by [@hackerhasid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013749/438458), I reworked the [deleted dotnet code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Printing/PaperSize@cs/1/PaperSize@cs) for my own purposes returning a **PaperSize** class instead of a **Point** structure as done by the original code.

I needed this in restricted security environments where printer access might be limited.  I found that the restricted access prevented me from iterating over printer defined page sizes.

A null is returned if the PaperKind is undefined or no longer supported.

NOTE: The **PaperSize** class stores the numbers as hundredths of an inch.

```
    private static PaperSize GetPaperSize(PaperKind kind)
    {
        // NOTE: This code is a resurrected and refactored version of code originally found at:
        // http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Printing/PaperSize@cs/1/PaperSize@cs

        var fnInches = new Func<double, double, PaperSize>((width, height) =>
        {
            Debug.Assert(width < 50 && height < 50, "You said inches, but you probably meant millimeters (" + width + ", " + height + ")");
            var ps = new PaperSize(kind.ToString(), (int)(width * 100), (int)(height * 100));
            ps.RawKind = (int)kind;
            return ps;
        });

        var fnMillimeters = new Func<double, double, PaperSize>((width, height) =>
        {
            Debug.Assert(width > 50 && height > 50, "You said millimeters, but you probably meant inches (" + width + ", " + height + ")");
            var ps = new PaperSize(kind.ToString(), (int)(width / 25.4 * 100), (int)(height / 25.4 * 100));
            ps.RawKind = (int)kind;
            return ps;
        });

        switch (kind)
        {
            case PaperKind.Letter: return fnInches(8.5, 11);
            case PaperKind.Legal: return fnInches(8.5, 14);
            case PaperKind.A4: return fnMillimeters(210, 297);
            case PaperKind.CSheet: return fnInches(17, 22);
            case PaperKind.DSheet: return fnInches(22, 34);
            case PaperKind.ESheet: return fnInches(34, 44);
            case PaperKind.LetterSmall: return fnInches(8.5, 11);
            case PaperKind.Tabloid: return fnInches(11, 17);
            case PaperKind.Ledger: return fnInches(17, 11);
            case PaperKind.Statement: return fnInches(5.5, 8.5);
            case PaperKind.Executive: return fnInches(7.25, 10.5);
            case PaperKind.A3: return fnMillimeters(297, 420);
            case PaperKind.A4Small: return fnMillimeters(210, 297);
            case PaperKind.A5: return fnMillimeters(148, 210);
            case PaperKind.B4: return fnMillimeters(250, 354);
            case PaperKind.B5: return fnMillimeters(182, 257);
            case PaperKind.Folio: return fnInches(8.5, 13);
            case PaperKind.Quarto: return fnMillimeters(215, 275);
            case PaperKind.Standard10x14: return fnInches(10, 14);
            case PaperKind.Standard11x17: return fnInches(11, 17);
            case PaperKind.Note: return fnInches(8.5, 11);
            case PaperKind.Number9Envelope: return fnInches(3.875, 8.875);
            case PaperKind.Number10Envelope: return fnInches(4.125, 9.5);
            case PaperKind.Number11Envelope: return fnInches(4.5, 10.375);
            case PaperKind.Number12Envelope: return fnInches(4.75, 11);
            case PaperKind.Number14Envelope: return fnInches(5, 11.5);
            case PaperKind.DLEnvelope: return fnMillimeters(110, 220);
            case PaperKind.C5Envelope: return fnMillimeters(162, 229);
            case PaperKind.C3Envelope: return fnMillimeters(324, 458);
            case PaperKind.C4Envelope: return fnMillimeters(229, 324);
            case PaperKind.C6Envelope: return fnMillimeters(114, 162);
            case PaperKind.C65Envelope: return fnMillimeters(114, 229);
            case PaperKind.B4Envelope: return fnMillimeters(250, 353);
            case PaperKind.B5Envelope: return fnMillimeters(176, 250);
            case PaperKind.B6Envelope: return fnMillimeters(176, 125);
            case PaperKind.ItalyEnvelope: return fnMillimeters(110, 230);
            case PaperKind.MonarchEnvelope: return fnInches(3.875, 7.5);
            case PaperKind.PersonalEnvelope: return fnInches(3.625, 6.5);
            case PaperKind.USStandardFanfold: return fnInches(14.875, 11);
            case PaperKind.GermanStandardFanfold: return fnInches(8.5, 12);
            case PaperKind.GermanLegalFanfold: return fnInches(8.5, 13);

            case PaperKind.JapanesePostcard: return fnMillimeters(100, 148);
            case PaperKind.Standard9x11: return fnInches(9, 11);
            case PaperKind.Standard10x11: return fnInches(10, 11);
            case PaperKind.Standard15x11: return fnInches(15, 11);
            case PaperKind.InviteEnvelope: return fnMillimeters(220, 220);
            //= SafeNativeMethods.DMPAPER_RESERVED_48, 
            //= SafeNativeMethods.DMPAPER_RESERVED_49,
            case PaperKind.LetterExtra: return fnInches(9.275, 12);
            case PaperKind.LegalExtra: return fnInches(9.275, 15);
            case PaperKind.TabloidExtra: return fnInches(11.69, 18);
            case PaperKind.A4Extra: return fnInches(9.27, 12.69);
            case PaperKind.LetterTransverse: return fnInches(8.275, 11);
            case PaperKind.A4Transverse: return fnMillimeters(210, 297);
            case PaperKind.LetterExtraTransverse: return fnInches(9.275, 12);
            case PaperKind.APlus: return fnMillimeters(227, 356);
            case PaperKind.BPlus: return fnMillimeters(305, 487);
            case PaperKind.LetterPlus: return fnInches(8.5, 12.69);
            case PaperKind.A4Plus: return fnMillimeters(210, 330);
            case PaperKind.A5Transverse: return fnMillimeters(148, 210);
            case PaperKind.B5Transverse: return fnMillimeters(182, 257);
            case PaperKind.A3Extra: return fnMillimeters(322, 445);
            case PaperKind.A5Extra: return fnMillimeters(174, 235);
            case PaperKind.B5Extra: return fnMillimeters(201, 276);
            case PaperKind.A2: return fnMillimeters(420, 594);
            case PaperKind.A3Transverse: return fnMillimeters(297, 420);
            case PaperKind.A3ExtraTransverse: return fnMillimeters(322, 445);

            case PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcard: return fnMillimeters(200, 148);
            case PaperKind.A6: return fnMillimeters(105, 148);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2: return fnMillimeters(240, 332);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3: return fnMillimeters(216, 277);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3: return fnMillimeters(120, 235);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4: return fnMillimeters(90, 205);
            case PaperKind.LetterRotated: return fnInches(11, 8.5);
            case PaperKind.A3Rotated: return fnMillimeters(420, 297);
            case PaperKind.A4Rotated: return fnMillimeters(297, 210);
            case PaperKind.A5Rotated: return fnMillimeters(210, 148);
            case PaperKind.JapanesePostcardRotated: return fnMillimeters(148, 100);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcardRotated: return fnMillimeters(148, 200);
            case PaperKind.A6Rotated: return fnMillimeters(148, 105);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2Rotated: return fnMillimeters(332, 240);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3Rotated: return fnMillimeters(277, 216);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3Rotated: return fnMillimeters(235, 120);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4Rotated: return fnMillimeters(205, 90);
            case PaperKind.Standard12x11: return fnInches(12, 11);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4: return fnMillimeters(105, 235);
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4Rotated: return fnMillimeters(235, 105);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```