# Why can I not call ToArray on a generic IEnumerable object?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> e) {
  return e.ToArray();
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Error 1   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` does not contain a
>   definition for `ToArray` and no extension method `ToArray` accepting a
>   first argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?

But the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) lists this method. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you missing a using directive?!

Comment: Did you add a `using System.Linq;` namespace to the file?

Comment: I've accidentally removed my Linq reference by using "remove unused usings" when I had not (yet) used any linq. Just something to keep an eye out for.

Comment: Read the error message again, in particular the parenthetical which is **explaining what is wrong**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you're on .NET 3.5 or later, you need to add the `using` directive to the top of your code file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You also need to have an assembly reference to `System.Core` (although this should be there by default for Visual Studio projects).

Answer (score 8):

You're missing `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

[`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) is an extension method implements on `IEnumerable<T>` as a part of [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx), so you have to add that using to make it work.